# HBase connection pooling and pooling configuration

Tags: hbase

The question is pretty simple, as HTablePool is deprecated. The first question is how to use HTable pooling as it is a heavy operation, the second question is where to configure the number of initial connections that are pooled ?

Comment: Were you able to find some other way?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can partially answer your question. Like you said, `HTablePool` is now deprecated ( see: [HBASE-6580](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6580)). It has, however, been replaced by `HConnection`. We can now use this.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
try (HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config)) {
    try (HTableInterface table = connection.getTable(tableName)) {
    ...
    }
}
```

and used further. I, however, don't think we can configure the number of initial connections which are pooled.